# RSA and SHA-256 encryption for signing using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, hash, rsa

I'm receiving XML in request from a Web Service API. It contains a signature, signed by the requester's private key, and I have to verify it by the requester public key. Then I have to send a response with a signature, signed by my private key.

This process should be done with RSA and SHA-256 in PHP.

I currently have the following code:

```php
$data_to_encrypt = "MsgBody..../MsgBody"; // xml 

$msgbody = simplexml_load_string($data_to_encrypt);
$result = $msgbody->xpath('//MsgBody'); 

openssl_private_encrypt(json_encode($result), $encrypted, $private_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

$signature = $encrypted;
$verify = openssl_verify($encrypt, $signature ,$publick_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
```

The result of $verify= 0. Why is it a bad verify?

Comment: what are you stuck on? Is most likely using [openssl_sign](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) but to be sure you should ask for docs or more details from said requester

Comment: Use `openssl_sign` instead. Probably the hash function indication is missing when you use `openssl_private_encrypt`. That whole function should be scrapped.

Answer (score 6):

The counterpart to [`openssl_private_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php) is [`openssl_public_decrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-decrypt.php). Both methods allow low level signing/verification with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding ([RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2)), where the data is implicitly not hashed, nor is the ID of the digest used prepended to the hash. I.e., for the result to be compliant with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, both must be done *explicitly*.

In contrast, hashing and adding the digest ID is *implicitly* taken into account in [`openssl_sign`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) and [`openssl_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php) in the context of RSA and PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, so the signature is automatically compliant with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Generally, the latter is the more efficient way for signing/verifying. However, `openssl_private_encrypt` also has a use, namely when not the data to be signed itself, but only the *already hashed data* is available for signing.

The issue in the code is the combination of `openssl_private_encrypt` and `openssl_verify`. Of course you can combine both, but then you have to implement hashing and adding the digest ID for `openssl_private_encrypt`, which is missing in the code. Alternatively (as already noted in the comments) `openssl_sign` can be applied, which is more efficient here.
Another inconsistency is that signing and verifying must be done on the same data. In the code, `json_encode($result)` is used for signing and `$encrypt` (from which `json_encode($result)` was derived) for verifying.

The following PHP code demonstrates the combination of `openssl_private_encrypt` and `openssl_verify` (see *Test 1*):

```
function getRSAKeys(){
    $keyPairResource = openssl_pkey_new(array("private_key_bits" => 2048, "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA)); 
    openssl_pkey_export($keyPairResource, $privateKey);
    return [$privateKey, openssl_pkey_get_details($keyPairResource)["key"]];
}

// Create test key
$newKeyPair = getRSAKeys();
$privateKey = $newKeyPair[0];
$publicKey = $newKeyPair[1];

// Test 1: openssl_private_encrypt and openssl_verify
$dataToSign = 'Test 1: The data to sign'; // Could correspond to e.g. json_encode($result) in the code
$dataToSignHashed = hash('sha256', $dataToSign, true);
$dataToSignHashedWithID = hex2bin("3031300d060960864801650304020105000420") . $dataToSignHashed; // ID from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#page-47
openssl_private_encrypt($dataToSignHashedWithID, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
$verified = openssl_verify($dataToSign, $signature, $publicKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
print($verified) . PHP_EOL;

// Test 2: openssl_sign and openssl_verify
$dataToSign = 'Test 2: The data to sign'; // Could correspond to e.g. json_encode($result) in the code
openssl_sign($dataToSign, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
$verified = openssl_verify($dataToSign, $signature, $publicKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
print($verified) . PHP_EOL;

// Test 3: openssl_private_encrypt and openssl_public_decrypt (without hashing and adding the digest id)
$dataToSign = 'Test 3: The data to sign'; // Could correspond to e.g. json_encode($result) in the code
openssl_private_encrypt($dataToSign, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
openssl_public_decrypt($signature, $decrypted, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
print($dataToSign === $decrypted) . PHP_EOL;
```

**Edit:** The last example is to be understood *purely technical* and should demonstrate that encryption with `openssl_private_encrypt` without hashing and without adding the ID can be decrypted with `openssl_public_decrypt`. In practice, hashing is applied when signing, see comment by *kelalaka* and e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12768/why-hash-the-message-before-signing-it-with-rsa). Both methods are not intended to sign/verify the message *directly*, but, as already mentioned above, to allow the user to sign/verify an *already hashed* message.

Comment: One should note that the hashing before signing is crucial for the security.